# Harmonic function with condition $\lim_{y\to\infty}u(x,y)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, alternative-proof, harmonic-functions

Could someone check if it's correct what I've done please?

> Solve the following problem by separation of variables $$\nabla^2u(x,y)=0,\ \ 0\le x\le\pi, y\ge0\\ u(0,y)=u(\pi,y)=0\\ u(x,0)=\big(\frac{x}{\pi}\big )^2\\ \lim_{y\to\infty}u(x,y)=0$$

Note that I haven't applied the condition $\lim_{y\to\infty}u(x,y)=0,$ because it doesn't make sense, if $y\to\infty,$ then $u$ goes $\infty$ aswell a not to zero.

Note 2. This was an exam question however it's kinda complicated,  calculating the coefficients $A_n$ for instance. Is there an alternative (easier) solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: If $y\to\infty$ then $u$ goes to infinity as well? Why in the world would you imagine this was so?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich :( because it's the exponential function, it grows very fast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made a sign error. The general solution should be

$$ u(x,y) = \sum_n A_ne^{-\sqrt{\lambda_n}y}X_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_ne^{-n y}\sin(n x) $$

The indeed goes to zero as $y\to \infty$, since the $X$ part is always bounded. 
We set $B_n=0$ *because* of this boundary condition (the bounded solution is just an assumption that wasn't stated).

Also, you don't really need the constant $D_n$ there, since it would just combine with $A_n$ to make one constant anyway.

The last part is straightforward

$$ A_n = \frac{\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^2\sin(n x)\ dx}{\int_0^\pi \sin^2(n x)\ dx} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^2\sin(n x)\ dx $$

This is (to me) the easiest part, since all you need to is solve the integral. Applying integration by parts twice gets it done. It's tedious, but not complicated.

Comment: Ah the sign..you're right.

Comment: I was checking again and realize the condition $u(\pi,y)=0$ was not applied, was it?

Comment: Is there a reason on why to integrate $\sin(x)$ with the explicit eigenvalue and not $\sqrt\lambda$?

Comment: That form of the eigenvalue was your mistake, which I've neglected to check. The right eigenvalues are there now.

Comment: It doesn't matter what form of the eigenvalue you integrate in, as long as the final solution is explicitly in terms of $n$

Comment: Why do you say that $\sqrt{\lambda_n}=n$ ? We have that $\sin(\sqrt \lambda x)=0$ thus $\sqrt\lambda=n\pi$

Comment: No. $X(\pi) = 0$, therefore $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) = 0$... You should really proofread you own answer.

Comment: But we also have $u(0,y)=0$

Comment: I think I understand. One last question is there another method to solve this?

Comment: Sure, another method is to use Green's function. I'm not an expert on any others. Honestly, separation of variables are the best method to use here. I understand your frustration with integrals, but they're the least of your problems.

Comment: ok, thanks Dylan. Mybe I'll put a bounty on this later expecting different ways to solve it.